# Form Data Append Method Not Working In Angular 8

Tags: javascript, php, html, angular, file-upload

I've been struggling with this problem for sometime now and its very frustrating. I've been trying to use Javascript's FormData to upload a file and it seem the file doesn't get sent to the server.

```
uploadCoverImages() {
    const form = new FormData();
    const files = this.coverImagesFiles; // const files is now a Files[] object

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const imageFile = files[i];
      console.log(imageFile); // return the right file data
      form.append('image', imageFile, imageFile.name);
      this.http.post(this.uploadUrl, form, { headers: this.headers }).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log('res : ' + res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log('err: ' + err); // always get an error saying file is empty
        }
      );
    }
}
```

This is my http header code:

```
getFileUploadHeader() {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ // Angular's HttpHeader
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Accept': 'application/json', // some google searches suggested i drop this but it still doesnt work
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    });
    return headers;
}
```

My PHP code (Laravel 5) is expecting a file with key like this:

```
public function imageUpload(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        return Reponse::json('file ok');
    }
    else
    {
        return Response::json('no file');
    }    
}
```

I just dont know why form data doesnt send the file or if am doing something wrong at the server side. How do i get this work. Please help!!!

Comment: Don’t set the Content-Type header yourself. The value you are trying to set is not sufficient - the _boundary_ used inside the request body needs to be appended to that. Most frameworks / libraries should handle that part automatically.

Comment: Also, you are looping over `files` here, suggesting there might be more than one. In that case, you need to append square brackets to the parameter name (`image[]`), otherwise PHP will not recognize this correctly, and overwrite all with the last value.

Comment: Are you getting any error on the network tab?
Here's a working example how to upload a file
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-df36c2

Comment: @misorude your suggestion worked thanks, after i removed the content-type in the headers it worked like a charm, thanks a lot you've really saved me a huge headache.